# Find nodes where 2 number ranges overlap

Tags: neo4j, cypher, cypher-3.1

I have nodes with the following properties

```
(n:User {valUpper:100, valLower:-100}) 
(m:User {valUpper:200, valLower: 0})
```

Using cypher is it possible to find if (m)'s range overlaps with (n)?

This is what I would have done in js..

```
if max(x2, y2) - min(x1, y1) < (x2 - x1) + (y2 - y1) {
     //Ranges Overlap
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the formula from your javascript example you could do it like this

```
... here you match for n and m ...
WITH n.valUpper as x1, n.valLower as y1, m.valUpper as x2, m.valLower as y2
RETURN apoc.coll.max([x2, y2]) - apoc.coll.min([x1, y1]) < (x2 - x1) + (y2 - y1)
```

Hope this helps.

Regards,
Tom

Comment: thanks @tom i didn't know about apoc, looks like a solid plugin :)

Comment: @gk103 it is THE plugin :-)

Answer (score 2):

Apoc is very worthy option. Just want to mention non apoc way for people who dont want to enable apoc.

```
WITH n.valUpper as x1, n.valLower as y1, m.valUpper as x2, m.valLower as y2
RETURN 
  CASE WHEN x2 > y2 THEN x2 ELSE y2 END - 
  CASE WHEN x1 < y1 THEN x1 ELSE y1 END 
  < (x2 - x1) + (y2 - y1)
```